# Rust: passing functions/filters to Tera templating

Tags: function, templates, rust, jinja2, tera

I have a Tera (Jinja2 alike) template which requires 2 functions to be imported. Raises expected function that takes 2 arguments. How do I approach this?

One of the functions:

```
#[derive(Serialize)]
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Color {
    White,
    Blue,
    Green,
    Yellow,
    Red,
}

fn bootstrap_table_color (e: Color) -> String {
    return match e {
        White => "".to_string(),
        Blue => "table-info".to_string(),
        Green => "table-success".to_string(),
        Yellow => "table-warning".to_string(),
        Red => "table-danger".to_string(),
    };
}
```

The template:

```
let mut htmlbuilder = tera::Tera::new("src/*.html").unwrap();
let mut context = tera::Context::new();
htmlbuilder.register_filter("bootstrap_table_color", bootstrap_table_color);
context.insert("allentries", &allentries);
let htmldata = htmlbuilder.render_str("

{% for e in allentries[0] %}
    <td class='{{ bootstrap_table_color(e=e.color) }}'>
        <a class='{{ bootstrap_text_color(e=e.color) }}' href='{{ e.filename }}'>
            {{ e.text }}
        </a>
    </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Error raised during compilation:

```
    error[E0593]: function is expected to take 2 arguments, but it takes 1 argument
   --> src/main.rs:151:55
    |
26  | fn bootstrap_table_color (e: Color) -> String {
    | --------------------------------------------- takes 1 argument
...
151 |     htmlbuilder.register_filter("bootstrap_table_color", bootstrap_table_color);
    |                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected function that takes 2 arguments
    |
    = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `tera::Filter` for `fn(Color) -> std::string::String {bootstrap_table_color}`
```